# how to dismiss the dropdown list of an autocompletebox in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, autocompletebox

is there anyway to programmatically dismiss the drop-down list of an autocompletebox? my use case is as follows.

MainPage.xaml passes a value to SearchPage.xaml (i.e. /SearchPage.xaml?query=someText).

in SearchPage.xaml.cs, i set,

```
autoCompleteBox.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["query"].
```

at this point, the drop-down list of suggested matches shows up. i don't want this behavior when the page is just navigated to.

i also tried the following to dismiss the drop-down list but it didn't help.

```
autoCompleteBox.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["query"];
autoCompleteBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
```

the drop-down list seems to go away from the AutoCompleteBox when it loses focuses, but i don't see a property/field to set to make it lose focus.

any help is appreciated.

well, i tinkered a bit and came up with a kludge. in the constructor of SearchPage.xaml.cs i have the following code.

```
autoCompleteBox.TextFilter += DummyFilter;
autoCompleteBox.GotFocus += (s,args) => {
 if(!isAutoCompleteBoxInit) {
  autoCompleteBox.TextFilter -= DummyFilter;
  autoCompleteBox.TextFilter += RealFilter;
 }
}
```

DummyFilter looks like the following.

```
bool DummyFilter(string search, string value) { return false; }
```

RealFilter looks like the following.

```
bool RealFilter(string search, string value) {
 if(null != value) return value.ToLower().StartsWith(search.ToLower());
}
```

in my OnNavigatedTo method, is where i set, autoCompleteBox.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["query"]. so when i do this now, the DummyFilter will always return false, so the drop-down list goes away. when the user focuses in on the AutoCompleteBox, i check if the correct Filter was already attached to the TextFilter property, if not, then i do a switch.

hope this helps some of you.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any other focusable control on the page?  Just set the focus somewhere else, and your problem should be solved.

Comment: no that did not work. i added a TextBlock and set its visibility to collapse at design time. when the page is navigated to, i called TextBlock.Focus(), and this did not help at all. the only way it works for me is what i said above.

Comment: @user373312 you can't set focus on something that is collapsed as it is removed from the visual tree

Comment: Have you tried this.Focus() to set the focus to the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

When you have changed the text of the AutoCompleteBox the dropdown will open. Only when the user has changed the text and there is a match then the dropdown will close.

Just change userInitiated to true and when there is a match the dropdown will close.

```
private void UpdateTextCompletion(bool userInitiated)
    {
        userInitiated = true; ...
```